# AJAX call to the same page, without a page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been having this problem for around a week now where I just cannot seem to get an AJAX call to communicate with PHP. This is my sample code I've made for this issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #showInfo
    {
      height: 100px; width: 400px;

      text-align: center;
      border: 2px solid darkslategray;

      position: absolute;
      top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
      margin: auto;

      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #showInfo p
    {
      font-size: 25px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#showInfo").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: { imageDir: "hello" },
          success: function(data) {
            alert("success");
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(data) { alert("error"); }
        });

        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="showInfo">
    <p> Show "defaultPfp.jpg" directory </p>
  </div>

  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['imageDir']))
      echo 'worked';
    else
    {
      echo 'didnt work';
    }
  ?>
</body>

</html>
```

For clarification, I want this code to be able to send an AJAX call once the #showInfo div is clicked. From here this is where the problem arises. I think that the PHP within the page isn't refreshing to gather the AJAX call's data. IF this is the problem, I have no clue what to do.

Other than this, I've tried adding event.preventDefault() before and after the AJAX call, and I've tried to add some ob_flush() calls all with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: A problem that is occuring is that the variable data in the AJAX call is not functioning correctly. console.log(data) returns the entire HTML page, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You have to have a specific PHP file available to call in order to update a page part. Ajaxing a PHP file which produces a complete page is a no-go.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have tried this, but I've retried this within the sample code and it still didn't work :/ Heres my AJAX call now just for reference: https://imgur.com/a/UMZcfQF

However, if I were to show the contents from another php file, wouldn't I just use include_once?

Comment: That is my point.. Do not try to ajax `index.html`. Create another PHP file... say `showinfo.php` which will output just that part.

Comment: index.php: https://imgur.com/a/6YFwze8 page.php: https://imgur.com/a/Fv53MMh

Even then using include_once 'page.php'; to see if php gathered the AJAX call information, this does not work.

Comment: Read [Understanding AJAX](https://www.codementor.io/@sheena/ajax-tutorial-web-development-du107rzaq)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette This does not help but thanks regardless